# Android AVD, CPU/ABI for x86 is missing

Tags: android, android-ndk, x86, device, android-virtual-device

I have my Intel x86 image installed in my SDK. I am currently running API 19. Previously, I was able to create and work with a Virtual Device running the x86 System Image. Everything worked fine until a couple of days back. 
I usually prefer to test my apps on a device with the Intel x86 processor so I didn't use the emulator much. Since, I had to have a couple of things fixed on my real device, I started using the emulator. I kept getting the HAXM not working error. So, I tried to fix it by enabling Inte VT-x. After I did that, I am not able to find the Intel x86 option in my ABI and I am unable to open the already existing emulator too. I would appreciate any help with this!